# C# Add mySQL Results to combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Hello I am trying to add names to a combobox but I keep getting only one result.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    locationName = reader.GetString("locationName");
    factoryLocationsCombo.Items.Add(locationName);
    reader.NextResult();
}
```

Isnt that the correct approach?

Comment: what is the exception you get? how man values do you expect? Is reader a normal SqlDtaReader?

Comment: @SebastianL I dont get an exception. I have 5 items and the combo box only shows the first one.

Comment: Is reader a normal SqlDataReader? what is your querystring?

Comment: @SebastianL I should have the reader.NextResult(); removed! Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no need for `reader.NextResult();`, which is used when reading the results of batch Transact-SQL statements. if you are having a single query that returns some rows(here `5` rows as you specified) and you need to iterate over those records, then `while(reader.Read())` will help you to do this iteration, So you can try like this, by removing that `reader.NextResult();`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  locationName = reader.GetString("locationName");
  factoryLocationsCombo.Items.Add(locationName);                   
}
```

Alternatively you can use SQLDataAdapter to get the query result to a DataTable and simply bind that datatable to the ComboBox, no need to bother about iterations and while.

Comment: That was correct! Thank you! :) I will flag it as correct answer in 7 minutes cause I am not yet allowed!

Comment: @LambrosHitiris: coool... Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Your:

```
while (reader.Read())
```

Already iterates your results. you don't need:

```
reader.NextResult()
```

For a better approach, follow this example:

```
List<Location> locations = new Location();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Location location = new Location();
    location.ID = reader.GetInt("locationID");
    location.Name = reader.GetString("locationName");
    locationss.Add(location);
}
factoryLocationsCombo.DataSource = locations;
factoryLocationsCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";
factoryLocationsCombo.DataMember = "ID";
factoryLocationsCombo.DataBind();
```